# Render template only when data is ready in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-template

In my Ionic 2 app I get data of an object from an API. Then I want to show details of this object in my template.

Problem is that the template tries to show the object before the object is loaded from the API which throws errors of course because object is undefined.

This is the flow:

`showRide()` has been called:

```
showRide(rideId) {
    this.navCtrl.push(DetailsPage, {
      rideId: rideId
    });
  }
```

DetailsPage component opens:

```
export class DetailsPage {

    rideId: any;
    ride: any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public rides: Rides) {
        this.rideId = this.navParams.get('rideId');
        this.rides.getRide(this.rideId).subscribe(response => { this.ride = response.ride });
    }

}
```

`this.rides.getRide` calls the method the gets the data from the API.

```
getRide(rideId) {
      var headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Authorization', 'Token token=' + this.authentification.token);
      return this.http.get('URL' + rideId , { headers: headers })
      .map(res => res.json());
    }
```

In my template I try to show the ID

```
{{ ride.id }}
```

Which gives me the error that id is not an attributes of undefined.

How do I make sure that my template only renders AFTER the object is available?

I tried to add: `*ngIf="ride"` to my ion-content. This works but messes up the entire layout. I am sure there is a better way of ding it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use safe navigation operator (`?`) to "protect" your template until REST call is finished and data is avilable:

```
{{ ride?.id }}
```

Read more about safe navigation operator [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator).

You can also simply assign initial value to `ride`, so it's not `undefined` at the moment of template rendering:

```
ride: any = {};
```

Comment: Thanks that works for most parts. My ride object has nested objects 'waypoints'. When I try to get waypoints[0]. I get the error cannot read 0 of undefined. When I inspect my object the waypoints are all there. Can I solve this with a similar technique? I tried: ride?.waypoints[0] but it brings me the above error.

Comment: @almo `waypoints` is an array? Unfortunately, safe navigation operator can't be used for arrays if I remember correctly, but they may have changed in one of the recent updates, I haven't read all changelogs.

Comment: @almo Try using `{{ ride?.waypoints && ride?.waypoints[0] }}`.